# With custom python module in ansible - How to import python modules installed on controller

Tags: python, ansible

I spent to whole day trying to figure this out. But without success :-(

I have a custom python module that I am using with an ansible play. This module runs on the remote node and I can import my own custom modules without problem. All was fine until I wanted to import an open source python module (monotonic) that I installed on the controller. I get the following error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'monotonic'

There is only 1 python interpreter (python3 in a container built using a base Ubuntu image). Sure enough, importing directly at the python command line works perfectly.

I understand that ansible gathers all the python code on the controller and transfers this to the remote node. But somehow this does not happen with monotonic (or any other installed open source packages). In fact, this used to work even with installed packages but I lost that ability somehow. May be I was just lucky but that luck disappeared after an ansible update... I presumed it is related to some search path between ansible and the installed python. For what its worth, Ubuntu's pip version apparently installs packages under /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/, where I can find the monotonic package (and jinja2, which I presumed was installed as a dependency to ansible....)

SO, my question us very simple, what is the proper environment variable to set to get access to the system installed packages for python?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible doesn't transfer any Python modules to the remote node. If your custom module has dependencies, you will need to arrange to install those in your playbook.

For example:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure that monotonic is installed on remote host
      pip:
        name: monotonic
        state: present

    - name: Use my custom module
      mycustommodule:
```

(Although according to the documentation for [`monotonic`](https://pypi.org/project/monotonic/), you don't need it if you're using Python 3.3 or newer; you can just use `time.monotonic` instead).

Comment: Thanks but monotonic is just one of them. And I can not install anything permanent on the remote; in some cases the bulk of the filesystem will be read-only anyway.

Comment: Back to your Ansible doesn't transfer,,, to the remote node. This is false, it does. At least that is what happens with an older installation of the controller where my plays work fine. (And yes I checked that monotonic was not already present on the remote node, which in fact is the same target remote I tested with the 2 controllers)

Comment: Ansible does not (and has never) transferred third-party modules to remote hosts. If you have many dependencies, you can use the same task I've shown here with a list, or use a `requirements.txt` style file.

Comment: Yes I was wrong. Turns out that my module was executed on the remote node instead of on the controller (and forgot it was supposed to run on the controller). The root  cause was that my custom plugin, which executes my module, was not loaded by newer ansible. With the old ansible, the plugin extension was sufficient for ansible to load the plugin. Now, it appears that it is the file location that dictates what kind of file this is. Not really a common way to work...